# Tensorflow JS, custom loss function, putting the pieces together

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, lstm, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow.js

I want to train a model to play a game. I have looked at Ping from pixel examples for reinforcement learning and based my code.

However, in contrast to that example, in my game the best move can not be predicted from a single frame. It is more like a game of poker, where you need to take in account previous moves. That is why I have chosen a model with a `LSTM`, like in the tutorials on generating text.

I came up with the following pieces of code, but have a hard time of putting the parts together:

```
/* This function should be fine*/
function createModel(lstmLayerSizes) {
  if (!Array.isArray(lstmLayerSizes)) {
    lstmLayerSizes = [lstmLayerSizes];
  }

  _model = tf.sequential();
  for (let i = 0; i < lstmLayerSizes.length; ++i) {
    const lstmLayerSize = lstmLayerSizes[i];
    _model.add(tf.layers.lstm({
      units: lstmLayerSize,
      returnSequences: i < lstmLayerSizes.length - 1,
      inputShape: i === 0 ? [_sampleLength, _indicatorCount] : undefined
    }));
  }
  _model.add(
    tf.layers.dense({
      units: numberOfActions,
      activation: 'softmax'
    }));
}

function compileModel(learningRate) {
  _optimizer = tf.train.rmsprop(learningRate);
  _model.compile({
    optimizer: _optimizer,
    loss: myLossFunction
  });
}

/* Should only have 2 parameters */
function myLossFunction(actions, labels, rewards) {
  var tsActions = tf.oneHot(actions, 3);
  var tsActionsFloat32 = tf.cast(tsActions, 'float32');
  var cross_entropies = tf.losses.softmaxCrossEntropy(tsActionsFloat32, labels);
  var loss = tf.sum(tf.mul(rewards, cross_entropies));
  return loss;
}

async function train(game) {
  const numEpochs = 10;
  const numOfSteps = 50;

  var observations = [];
  var predictions = [];
  var actions = [];

  compileModel(0.01);
  for (let i = 0; i < numEpochs; ++i) {
    console.log(`epoch ${i}, start`)
    var step = game.init();
    for (let s = 0; s < numOfSteps; s++) {
      var observation = step.context;
      var prediction = predict(observation);
      var action = sampleFromProbability(prediction);
      step = game.doAction(action);

      observations.push([observation]);
      predictions = predictions.concat(Array.from(prediction.dataSync()));
      actions.push(action);
    }

    var rewards = calculateRewards(step, referenceFrame, numOfSteps);
    var tsActions = tf.tensor1d(actions);
    var tsPredictions = tf.tensor2d(predictions, [50, 3], 'float32');
    var tsRewards = tf.tensor1d(rewards);
    var tsObservations = tf.tensor3d(observations, [50, 1, 5])


    /* Gives a runtime error saying no variables can be found */
    //_optimizer.minimize(() => { return myLossFunction(actions, tsPredictions, rewards); } );

    /* invallid loss function, and should take the rewards into account */
    //await _model.fit(tsObservations, tsPredictions);

    console.log(`epoch ${i}, stop`)

    actions = [];
    predictions = [];
    rewards = [];
  }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is using an Actor - Critic network. I'm also experimenting with a similar implementation.
You can check it out here:
https://sergiuionescu.github.io/esp32-auto-car/sym/sym.html